# Statistical genetics: Allele frequencies that follow a Dirichlet distribution

Tags: genetics, evolution, theoretical-biology, population-genetics, statistics

From [Foll and Gagiotti (2008)](http://www.genetics.org/content/180/2/977) (software [BayeScan](http://cmpg.unibe.ch/software/BayeScan/)). They consider a model where several subpopulation are derived from a unique ancestral population.

> We consider a set of $I$ loci and let $K_i$ be the number of alleles at the $i^{th}$ locus. The extent of differentiation at locus $i$ between subpopulation $j$ and the ancestral population is measured by $F^{ij}_{ST}$ and is the result of its demographic history. Let $p_i=\{p_{ik}\}$ denote the allele frequencies of the ancestral population at locus $i$, where $p_{ik}$ is the frequency
>   of the allele $k$ at locus $i$ $\left(\sum_k p_{ik} = 1\right)$. We use $\mathbf {p} = \{\mathbf {p_i}\}$ to denote the entire set of allele frequencies of the ancestral population and $\mathbf {\tilde p_{ij}} = \{ \tilde p_{ijk}\}$ to denote the current allele frequencies at locus $i$ for subpopulation $j$. Under these assumptions, the allele frequencies at locus $i$ in subpopulation $j$ follow a Dirichlet distribution with parameters $\theta_{ij}\mathbf {p_i}$,
>
> $$\mathbf {\tilde p_{ij}}  \space \tilde \space\space  \text{Dir}(\theta_{ij} p_{i1}, ..., \theta_{ij}p_{iK_i})$$
>
> , where
>
> $$\theta_{ij} = \frac{1}{F^{ij}_{ST}}-1$$

<sup>(I don't have much experience with Dirichlet distributions but I understand its definition and its usefulness in bayesian statistics).</sup>

**Can you please help me to understand why $\mathbf {\tilde p_{ij}}$ follows this Dirichlet distribution?**

Calling the $j^{th}$ parameter of the Dirichlet distribution, $\alpha_j$, I typically don't understand why they "chose" $\alpha_j = \left(\frac{1}{F^{ij}_{ST}}-1\right) p_{ij}$ and not, say just $\alpha_j = F^{ij}_{ST} p_{ij}$ or anything else.

Comment: It looks like it is a solution to an integral equation as described in Sewall Wright's Evolution in Mendelian Populations, Section Nonrecurrent Mutation https://www.genetics.org/content/genetics/16/2/97.full.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Largely an informed guess based on properties of distributions rather than specific knowledge of statistical genetics: a beta distribution is useful for modeling the frequencies of two alleles at one locus. A [Dirichelet distribution](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~horte005/docs/Dirichletdistribution.pdf), which is a multivariate generalization of a beta distribution, would thus be useful for modeling a *set* of loci.

The flip side is to think of beta as just a special case of Dirichelet: if you only have one locus, beta works. If you have multiple loci, then Dirichelet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, those are things I know about statistics (+1 anyway as a thanks). I fail to understand why typically $\alpha_j = \left(\frac{1}{F^{ij}_{ST}}-1\right) p_{ij}$ and not, say just $\alpha_j = F^{ij}_{ST} p_{ij}$ or anything else. (I will add this precision in my question).